# Show all child <ui> and <li> within an <li> tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a nested 'ul' 'li' tree. On an instance, I show only certain 'li' based on a particular name and others are hidden. SAy, I have a tree like this:

- **branch1**

  - **twig1**

    - leaf1
  - ***twig2***
- **Branch2**

  - **twig3**

What I need is when I filter branch1 it should show twig1, twig2 and leaf1 as well(). Now it shows only parent branch1. How can I show child nodes too? I give the text to filter as input  via a text box. Please help me... Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {

    var filter = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("ul li").each(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
        jQuery(this).hide();
      } else {
        jQuery(this).show();
        jQuery(this).children().show();
      }
    });
  });

  function func() {
    alert("Onclick function...");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />

<ul id="mytree">
  <li>
    Branch1
    <ul>
      <li>twig1
        <ul>
          <li>leaf1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        twig2
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Branch2
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```js
      $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {

        var filter = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery("#mytree>li").each(function() {
          if (jQuery(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
              jQuery(this).hide();
          } else {
            jQuery(this).show();
            jQuery(this).find('li').show();
          }
        });
      });

      function func() {
        alert("Onclick function...");
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />

<ul id="mytree">

  <li>
    Branch1
    <ul>
      <li>twig1
        <ul>
          <li>leaf1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        twig2
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Branch2
  </li>
</ul>
```

.text() function returns text of element including subitems. So you don't need to cycle every **li** item. Only "root" items are enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use `>` to only reference direct children of your #mytree element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function (evt) {

    var filter = jQuery(this).val();
    $("#mytree > li").each(function () {
      if (jQuery(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
        jQuery(this).hide();
      } else {
        jQuery(this).show();
        jQuery(this).children().show();
      }
    });
  });

  function func() {
    alert("Onclick function...");
  }

});
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. If you type leaf, it shows twig2 as well. OR you type twig1, it will show you twig2 as well and vice-versa. Please check.
https://jsfiddle.net/abhiagnitk/xysh0s19/

Answer (score 1):

You only need to reference the direct childs of outer  while searching for text match. For that you must replace

```
jQuery("ul li").each(function() {
```

with

```
jQuery("#mytree > li").each(function() {
```

It will start working then:
I have created a fiddle at: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abhishek1608/aa9p9fsm/2/)